# Need a alternator for a 94 nissan pathfinder Le V6

Tags: nissan, alternator, pathfinder, part-interchange

I have a 94 Nissan Pathfinder LE V6 and I wanna know if there is any other parts that would b compatible or a perfect fit for my suv beside an D21 hardbody, altima wit a v6 motor or an Infinity G35 I'm badly in need to know so I can get my suv running again so I can go to work.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see as a fit for your Pathfinder is this:

- 91-94 Pathfinder
- 91-94 D21 Pickup

That is it.

Comment: Thank you very much coz I was out here looking for an altima as well n I was stressing out really bad. You helped me alot